# Using tensor calculus in thermodynamics :

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, tensor-calculus, thermal-conductivity

This is my first post here in Physics Exchange, I hope I'll find my questions answers here. As you all read in the title "Using tensors in thermodynamics" basically that was a problem in the university and I really liked it.

> Let $h_i, i=1,2,3,$ the heat quantities crosses the are of a material during a $t$ in the directions perpendicular to an axis $0x_i$. this heat flows under the influence of a temperature gradient $T$. The componenets $h_i$ are the one of the vector $\boldsymbol{h}$

Well I can't say that we can use Fourier Law :
$$h_i=-k_{ij} \frac{\partial T}{\partial x_j} $$

If is it true can $k_{ij}$ be the components of the 'Thermal conductivity tensor'?

Can we just prove that $\mathbf{div \ h}=0 $ without considering $k_{ij}=0$ if $i\neq j$ ?

Comment: Please be more clear while you are asking a question ! and as I understood from your question all what you need is to start from the first equation and compute $\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial x_i} =0 $ where $h_i $ can be expressed as you said.

Comment: At steady state, the divergence of the heat flux vector is always zero, irrespective to the anisotropy of the thermal conductivity tensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished your question's answer, here's my attempts even I had some misunderstanding of you question but I hope it helps you :

Considering that :
$$\mathbf{div \ h}=0$$ 
and According to Fourier law of thermo :
$$h_i=-k_{ij}\frac{\partial T}{\partial x_j}$$ 
In index form  the 1st equation can be written :
$$\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial x_i}=0$$
Using what you gave : 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\bigg(-k_{ij}\frac{\partial T}{\partial x_j}\bigg)=0$$
what we got was the equation of the distracting temperatures in stationary regime, $k_{ij}$ vary slightly in a high temperature : 
$$k_{ij} \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}=0 \qquad(1)$$
In Fourier law we have the components of $\frac{\partial T}{\partial x_j}$ are the contracted product of $k_{ij}$ so your first question was true $k_{ij}$ are the components of a Tensor what we call thermal conductivity tensor.

The tensor $k_{ij}$ if $i\neq j $ the equation $(1)$ can be written as (by the way $k_{1}=k_{11}, \ k_{2}=k_{22}, \ k_{3}=k_{33}$):
$$k_1 \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x_1^2}+k_2 \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x_2^2}+k_3 \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x_3^2}$$
So it does not influence on the heat even if $\mathbf{div \ h}=0$

Good luck !

Comment: Why you used $k_{ij}, i=j$ is it false to consider $i\neq j$

Comment: The tensor take a special form I'll add this to my answer

Comment: It makes a sense right now, Thanks for answering my question !